# I want to output two large modals that divide the screen into two

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

current modal is this
[image: al]

I want to divide the above modal into two modals as shown below.

For example
[image]

my code

click bootstrap button by jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id;
    $("#todo_list a[class='title_for_list']").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        id = $(this).attr('id');

        window.history.pushState("", "", '/todo/'+id)
        $.get(id)
            .done((html) => {
                $('#myModal_button').hide();
                $("#myModal").html(html)
                $( "#myModal_button" ).trigger("click");
                // $( "#myModal_button3" ).trigger("click");
            })
            .fail(() => {
                console.log("fail");
            })
            .always(() => {
                console.log('always');
            })
    });
})
```

modal button

```
  <button id="btnModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">
    Open modal
  </button>
```

modal((Modal is completed using received html)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    12
</div>
```

modal content

```
https://github.com/hyunsokstar/django_inflearn2/blob/master/todo/templates/todo/_todo_detail.html
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use two modals by button click event and use different id's for `modal`

```
 #myModal
    {
     left:50% !important; 
     width:48% !important;
    }

    #myModalTwo
    {
     right:50% !important; 
      width:48% !important;
    }
```

```js
$("#btnModal").click(function() {
 $("#myModalTwo").modal("show");
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
})
```

```css
#myModal
{
 left:50% !important; 
 width:48% !important;
}

#myModalTwo
{
 right:50% !important; 
  width:48% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button id="btnModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal" id="myModalTwo">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for informing

I'll apply right away. Thank you.

Comment: @HyK if you add your html in your question it will be easy to resolve

Comment: The template code you gave me was successful when I ran it.

Let's apply it to my code.

thank you for telling me